# I need to printout -grep results to a file, How? (Windows OS)

Tags: windows, cmd, grep

I have a problem, which I'd previously solved, but I got a system error and lost the saved backups of my command lines.

I just want to print out the result of a command directly to a file after I get it parsed through a windows port of `grep`.

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\video.webm" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - > "C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 | -grep silencedetect "C:\!TEMP.txt" > "C:\!TEMP.txt" & type "C:\!TEMP.txt"
```

OR

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\video.webm" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - | -grep silencedetect > "C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 & type "C:\!TEMP.txt"
```

From what I recall, the command didn't work due to an issue whereby `cmd` itself printed the incomplete result from `ffmpeg` before being fully be parsed by `grep`. The solution to this, if I remember correctly, was to switch places of some pieces of the command line and shorten it a little. I'm almost sure that I didn't add anything else to that used in the sample below, *(maybe `stdout` and `&`/`&&`, not sure)*.

On my attempts today it either didn't output, or gave me an error that the `file is already in use`.

Can someone please help me?

*I don't want, and didn't need to use, more than one file. If I try to split it a little it looks silly.*

Comment: The general syntax would be a little more like this, for what you've submitted as code. ```%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /U /K ""ffmpeg.exe" CommandArguments 1>NUL 2>&1 | "grep.exe" CommandArguments 1>"OutputFile.ext" && Type "OutputFile.ext""```. We are however not here to rewrite your code according to a set of requirements, regardless of your backstory. I would also be interested to understand why you need to use `grep` as opposed to the built in `find.exe` or `findstr.exe` utilities.

Comment: thank you for the attempt, but still doesn't work, it could have work on a general situation, but I suspect its fails on a similar unknown reason as my other attempts, it simply prints out empty outputs.
I guess that I noted down some compatibility reasons through tests (my usual behaviour) for why I didn't used find.exe or findstr.exe on my other more complex syntaxes at the time and then to keep a standard I did the same on this portion, though I can't be sure, I can't remember anymore by myself since I don't have the notes to help me to recall.

Comment: I didn't provide it as an answer to your question, dannyhelMont. What I offered was simply the appropriate syntax for what you submitted as code. If you want help for a single specific issue, please explain using real world information, the exact task, instead of expecting us to formulate a solution using exactly the commands and utilities you've stated. We need to know the output from `ffmpeg`, and what you want the content of the resulting file to contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax that I used that needed a fix:

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\video.webm" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - | -grep silencedetect >"C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 & type "C:\!TEMP.txt"
```

the solution that I forgot and then asked for, which I said was silly:

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\video.webm" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - 2>&1 | -grep silencedetect >"C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 & type "C:\!TEMP.txt"
```

Then, just adding this "2>&1" after ffmpeg's arguments was enough, no matter the setup/output/etc, anyone could use it without further specificities.

Well, now I'm facing just another issue that is more like a small nuisance, and maybe I'll be able to get an answer here without having to start another topic, for this:

```
cmd /U /k ffmpeg -i "C:\video.webm" -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - 2>&1 | FOR /F "tokens=8" %f in ('findstr "silence_duration:"') do @echo %f >>"C:\!TEMP.txt" 2>&1 & type "C:\TEMP.txt"
```

As I did have to use Echo to be able to printout to the file(otherwise if nothing in place it doesn't printsout), I was also forced to use it as Append(>>),and not(>) that would be ideal for me since I don't want to mix different file outputs, Because while Echo is able to print to console with all its outputs when multiple requested strings were found with (>), printing to file this way just gets the last occurency of it; So, please if anyone reading this Actually knows an alternative to Echo on this situation Or a way to workaround on this syntax to be able to fully printout to a file through(>) what is?
...but please,if you don't know,don't answer/bloat on it, then I'll simply create another thread for this specific matter, thanks again in advance.